# Is there a standardized format for file extensions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, file-extension

I am building a node.js app which takes 2 arguments, the first is a file-extension. I would like to validate the input and make sure the user has provided a valid file-extension string.

Is there a universal format which file-extensions cannot break?

I am thinking probably [dot][char][char][char][char] where the two first chars are required and the rest are optional (.js, .jpg .json etc.). But perhaps it isn't so?

Comment: `Is there a universal format which file-extensions cannot break?`  No, because file-system's are not universal.  Even no extension in most OS's is valid,.  What is it your trying to avoid?

Comment: Good point. Would you go for a specific "most-cases" scenario though? or just accept any extension as long as it is a string? (I basically just need to search through a directory for file with the extension, and could just say didn't find files with this extension).

Comment: Think of `.c` / `.h` for C/C++ files, `.class` for Java, and we could easily come up with dozens of exceptions to your rule.

Comment: This has more than a few exceptions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_filename_extensions  :-)

Comment: some OSes like linux and mac don't even make use of file extensions.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename_extension

Comment: Ahh I see. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why the need to validate file extensions? If this is part of a service to upload files, would you not write a whitelist for file extensions to check against? If you want to check among known file extensions, you could use the IANA database for such: http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml